# Link tag from react-router-dom reduces width of img inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a map function

```
{topData.map((element, indx) => {
  return (
    <img
      key={indx}
      src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${element.poster_path}`}
      alt={element.title}
      width="15%"
    />
  );
})}
```

which gives an output like [Output for above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THGe6.jpg)

But when I add a `<Link>` tag as a parent for thr `img` tag, the size of the images reduce a lot. Something like this
[Output with Link tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEHho.png)
Code with the `<Link>` tag (just for clarification)

```
{topData.map((element, indx) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/movie/${element.id`} key={indx}>
      <img
        key={indx}
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${element.poster_path}`}
        alt={element.title}
        width="15%"
      />
    </Link>
  );
})}
```

The `<Link>` is from `react-router-dom`